# Does ruby Dalli gem support auto-heal/auto-reconnect by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dalli

Does ruby Dalli gem support auto-heal/auto-reconnect by default?

or

is there a way to enable auto-heal/auto-reconnect?

Comment: pardon my question but what does auto-heal/auto-reconnect mean here ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `dalli` in conjunction with [connection_pool](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool) from the same author.  The README specifically mentions the self-healing nature of `dalli` connections, but provisioning spares as needed can provide appropriate failover.